# Scanning through a file in C

Tags: c, file, loops, scanning

So I have the following in my text document:

```
7
PERSON Sarah 20 5 50
PERSON Jordan 30 10 30
PERSON James 25 42 56.50
GROUP STEEL 2
Martin 21 5 80.50
Martha 25 10 79.75
PERSON Hector 38 10 100.50
PERSON Charles 18 5 35
GROUP LUMBER 3
Jill 19 5 91
Aaron 25 10 98
Mark 28 42 152.80
```

So I'm trying to get my code to loop through all of the names here and print out info. The name represents the person's name, the first number represents age, the second number represents kilometers ran, and the third number represents amount raised. PERSON represents an individual person, whilst group represents multiple individuals. The 7 in the first line represents the total number of PERSONS and GROUPS; there are 5 people labeled PERSON and 2 groups labeled GROUP.

However, my code is only printing out the information for everyone with the label of PERSON. How can I get my code to print the name of the group along with the information for its members? Here is my code (not completely, but to show what I'm trying to do):

```
FILE * ifp = fopen("race01.txt", "r");
int numPeople, i, num = 1;
struct person individual;

fscanf(ifp, "%d", &numPeople);

for(i = 0; i < numPeople; i++) {
        fscanf(ifp, "%s %s %d %d %f", individual.name, individual.name, &individual.age, &individual.event, &individual.money);

        if (individual.event == 42) {
            printf("%s registered for the marathon race! They have been assigned the number %d\n", individual.name, num);
        }
        else {
            printf("%s registered for the %dk race! They have been assigned the number %d\n", individual.name, individual.event, num);
        }

        num++;
    }
```

I've tried all sorts of variations, from a nested for loop to additional scanning line, but nothing seems to cover the "groups".

Comment: You should check the return values from `fscanf()`.  You're going to need to read the first word on each line and analyze it and decide what to do with the rest of the line.  If the word is PERSON, you process the rest of the line one way; if it is GROUP, you'll read the rest of the line and then process the relevant number of subsequent lines as 'im-PERSONAL' people lines, roughly speaking.  How you store the data is a separate issue — there are many ways to do that.

Comment: can u show us "struct person"

Comment: to start, this line: `fscanf(ifp, "%d", &numPeople);` is getting the number of groups+people that are not in a group.   However, reading a `group` line should be causing a branch to loop reading the number of people in that group and displaying each person, within the group, info.  So the code should only read the first field to split on `group` or `person` and then read the rest of the field(s) in the line.   BTW: always check the returned value from `fscanf()` to assure the operation was successful

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the variable `numpeople` is very misleading.  that number is actually the number of separate 'header' lines in the file, not the total number of lines in the file.

Comment: When asking a question about a run time problem, post the actual input (you did) post the expected output (missing)  post the actual output (missing) and post a short code that cleanly compiles and still shows the problem (you didn't)

Comment: the posted code talks about a `42` event, but none of the input data is identified as being an event number.  Have you mixed up the question with some unrelated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jonathan said you should check if the first string you read is "PERSON" or "GROUP". If it equals "PERSON", you read information (name, age etc...) about this person, if it equals "GROUP", you should read the number of persons in that group and then read information about each person present in that group. Use functions like "strcmp" to compare two strings.
I have a modified version of your code below, it compiles and works fine.
I created a function named "print_raceinfo" which prints information about a person

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

#define NAME_MAX 25

struct person {
   char name[NAME_MAX];
   int age;
   int event;
   float money;
};

void print_raceinfo(struct person individual, int num)
{
    if (individual.event == 42) {
        printf("%s registered for the marathon race! They have been assigned the number %d\n", individual.name, num);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s registered for the %dk race! They have been assigned the number %d\n", individual.name, individual.event, num);
    }
}

int main(){

    FILE *fp;
    int numPeople, i, num = 1;
    struct person individual;
    char person_or_group[NAME_MAX];
    char group_name[NAME_MAX];
    int numpeople_in_group, j;

    fp = fopen("F://repoexample/race.txt", "r+");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &numPeople);

    for(i = 0; i < numPeople; i++) {

        fscanf(fp, "%s", person_or_group);

        //Compare the first 6 characters of string person_or_group with "PERSON"
        if (strncmp(person_or_group, "PERSON", 6) == 0) {

            fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %f", individual.name, &individual.age, &individual.event, &individual.money);

            print_raceinfo(individual, num);

            num++;
        }
        else if (strncmp(person_or_group, "GROUP", 5) == 0){

                //Read group name and number of people in that group
                fscanf(fp, "%s %d", group_name, &numpeople_in_group);

                for (j = 0; j<numpeople_in_group; j++) {

                    //Extract information for each person in that group
                    fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d %f", individual.name, &individual.age, &individual.event, &individual.money);

                    print_raceinfo(individual, num);

                    num++;
                }
        }

   }

    printf("Total number of persons = %d\n", num - 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
[image: SEE OUTPUT]

Comment: Print the group name as well. That makes your answer complete.

Comment: Ah, this is precisely what I was looking for. It seems that I set up my nested for loop incorrectly after scanning the variables. Thank you for writing this out, it helps a lot! I know exactly where I messed up.